# fast conversion of milliseconds to date

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Dataframe has over 10billion records with time stored as a bigint in milliseconds since 1/1/1970.  I need that as a date - applying transformation as shown below.  Is there a faster way of doing this?

```
spark.createDataFrame([[1365742800000],[1366866000000]], schema=["origdt"])\
  .withColumn("newdt", F.to_date((F.col("origdt")/1000).cast(TimestampType()))).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Transformation which you have done is fine, to increase speed to you can increase cluster size or increase partitions using `repartition` to utilize all the cores at a time.